# ggplot2::geom_text(): how to display all factor levels, but suppress specific values like '0':

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

Here is code to give context to my question:

```
set.seed(1); tibble(x=factor(sample(LETTERS[1:7],7,replace = T),levels = LETTERS[1:7])) %>% group_by_all() %>% count(x,.drop = F) %>% 
ggplot(mapping = aes(x=x,y=n))+geom_bar(stat="identity")+geom_text(
    aes(label = n, y = n + 0.05),
    position = position_dodge(1),
    vjust = 0)
```

I want ALL of the levels of the variable x to be displayed on the x-axis (LETTERS[1:7]).  For each Level with n>0, I want the value to display atop the bar for that level.  For each level with n==0, I want the value label to NOT be displayed.  Currently, the plot displays the 0 for 'empty' factor levels c("C","F"), and I want to suppress the display of '0's for those levels, but still display "C", and "F" on the x-axis.

[image: current plot]

I hope someone might be able to help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple `ifelse()` will do it.  You can enter any text you like for example `ifelse( n>0, n , "No Data")`

```
library( tidyr)
library( ggplot2)
library( dplyr )


set.seed(1); tibble(x=factor(sample(LETTERS[1:7],7,replace = T),levels = LETTERS[1:7])) %>% group_by_all() %>% count(x,.drop = F) %>% 
ggplot(mapping = aes(x=x,y=n))+geom_bar(stat="identity")+
    geom_text(
    aes(label = ifelse( n>0, n , ""), y = n + 0.05),
    position = position_dodge(1),
    vjust = 0)
```

[image: example graph without zeros]

Answer (score 2):

You pass a function to the data argument inside geom_test, for this example you can do a subset on the piped data (referred as `.x`):

```
set.seed(1); 
tibble(x=factor(sample(LETTERS[1:7],7,replace = T),levels = LETTERS[1:7])) %>% group_by_all() %>% count(x,.drop = F) %>% 
ggplot(mapping = aes(x=x,y=n))+geom_bar(stat="identity")+
geom_text(data=~subset(.x,n>0),
    aes(label = n, y = n + 0.05),
    position = position_dodge(1),
    vjust = 0)
```